# Why is the Android emulator displaying "unfortunately my_app_name has stopped"?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried to make an Android app for geolocation using GPS, but when I run the emulator, I get this message: `appname HAS unfortunately stopped.` Why do I get this? My code has no errors.

My .java:

```
package com.android.geolocalisation3;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Geo3MainActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;

    private LocationManager lm;

    private double latitude=122;
    private double longitude=37;
    private double altitude=0;
    private float accuracy=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geo3_main);

        mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(17);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0,
                    this);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0,
                this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            mapView.setSatellite(false);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_geo3_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //altitude = location.getAltitude();
        ///accuracy = location.getAccuracy();

        String msg = String.format(
                getResources().getString(R.string.new_location), latitude,
                longitude, altitude, accuracy);
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setCenter(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        String msg = String.format(
                getResources().getString(R.string.provider_disabled), provider);
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        String msg = String.format(
                getResources().getString(R.string.provider_enabled), provider);
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        String newStatus = "";
        switch (status) {
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            newStatus = "OUT_OF_SERVICE";
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            newStatus = "TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE";
            break;
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            newStatus = "AVAILABLE";
            break;
        }
        String msg = String.format(
                getResources().getString(R.string.provider_disabled), provider,
                newStatus);
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My log errors:

```
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:137)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:41)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:681)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:679)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor.readFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:75)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:34)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:30)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:369)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:301)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:68)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:56)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.<init>(ContentResolver.java:1835)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:392)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:301)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:68)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:56)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-28 00:00:01.144: E/StrictMode(621):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-28 00:00:45.364: E/PowerManagerService(157): Excessive delay setting brightness: 144ms, mask=2
07-28 00:00:45.544: E/PowerManagerService(157): Excessive delay setting brightness: 139ms, mask=2
07-28 00:00:45.764: E/PowerManagerService(157): Excessive delay setting brightness: 211ms, mask=2
07-28 00:00:45.994: E/PowerManagerService(157): Excessive delay setting brightness: 224ms, mask=2
07-28 00:05:21.293: E/ThrottleService(157): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: @Jon, [that's SO policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140162/flagging-non-english-questions). I've translated this question, but that's just a courtesy.

Comment: anyway as a comment about the question, does the emulator have GPS support?

Comment: [Here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow), @Jon.

Comment: I have added GPS support -> the same message from the emulator "unfortunately app has stopped"

Answer (score 3):

Somehow the formatting of your log messages was lost, making them very hard to read.

The first lines of the log messages give the clue:

```
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
07-28 00:00:01.054: E/StrictMode(621): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
```

Certain objects such as files or cursors need to be explicitly closed. Simply dropping the reference to them isn't good enough. Failing to close the object causes a resource leak, which the system detects and reacts to by killing your app.

Unfortunately, the stack trace only shows you where the leak was detected, not what originally caused it.

Are there parts of your code you're not showing us that relate to databases?  The log messages indicate a problem with a Cursor object.

Assuming you are using databases, look into your database access code and make SURE you close every cursor and database you open.  Make sure all 'return' statements in your database-handling functions close the relevant objects before returning.  Make sure you catch all possible exceptions and close your cursor objects before letting the exception go up the stack. I make liberal use of finally{} blocks for this.

My database code typically looks like this:

```
protected DbRec findById(String ident) {
    DbRec rval;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        if( (cursor = findCursorById(ident)) == null )
            return null;
        rval = newRecord();
        rval.fillFromCursor(cursor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read database record: " + e);
        rval = null;
    } finally {
        if( cursor != null ) cursor.close();
    }
    return rval;
}
```

---

ETA: I've taken the liberty of pasting the log messages from your comments:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(808): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.geolocalisation3/com.android.geolocalisation3.Geo3MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requested provider network doesn't exisit
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(808): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requested provider network doesn't exisit
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:482)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at com.android.geolocalisation3.Geo3MainActivity.onResume(Geo3MainActivity.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
E/AndroidRuntime(808): ... 12 more
```

This is a different error than before. It looks like the name of the location provider (e.g. "gps" was saved wrong in `onSaveInstanceState()` which caused a crash when the application restarted.

Comment: : E/(): Device disconnected
        07-30 08:58:19.618: E/Trace(808): error opening trace       file:No such file or directory (2)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.geolocalisation3/com.android.geolocalisation3.Geo3MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requested provider network doesn't exisit

Comment: 07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

Comment: 07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

Comment: 07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

Comment: 07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requested provider network doesn't exisit
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)

Comment: 07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:660)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:482)
        07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.android.geolocalisation3.Geo3MainActivity.onResume(Geo3MainActivity.java:49)

Comment: 07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
     07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
       07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
      07-30 08:58:21.758: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  ... 12 more

Comment: 07-30 09:00:35.647: E/PowerManagerService(158): Excessive delay setting brightness: 139ms, mask=2
      07-30 09:12:39.247: E/ThrottleService(158): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
       : E/(): Device disconnected
@EDWARD

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the emulator for the API level 16 is not able to register a NETWORK_PROVIDER listener. It worked just fine in level 10 emulator. I didn't test any other SDK versions.

I just added a check for the availability of the network provider to avoid this issue. You already did it for the GPS provider.

```
if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
```

I hope this helps.

J